# Websocket connection to AppSync: ErrorCode 400 'NoProtocolError'

Tags: javascript, websocket, aws-appsync

I'm trying to make a direct websocket connection to appsync, but right after connecting I get keep getting an `NoProtocolError` error  (
`{"payload":{"errors":[{"message":"NoProtocolError","errorCode":400}]},"type":"connection_error"}'`)

This is my code

```
let ws = undefined;

const startWebsocket = () => {
    const url = 'wss://XXXX.appsync-realtime-api.YYYY.amazonaws.com/graphql';
    ws = new WebSocket(url);

    // just log everything
    ws.onopen    = (e) => {console.log('Socket opened',   e);};
    ws.onmessage = (e) => {console.log('Msg    received', e);};
    ws.onclose   = (e) => {console.log('Socket closed',   e);};
    ws.onerror   = (e) => {console.log('Socket error',    e);};
};
```

Answer (score 5):

## Regarding the immediate question

The message is referring to the second parameter of the Websocket constructor: `protocols`. ([MDN reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/WebSocket))

You need to specify the protocol (more precise *subprotocol*) like below:

```
ws = new WebSocket(url, ['graphql-ws']);
```

#### However

Be aware, that you're also missing header information, payload information and the whole handshake.

Only changing adding the protocol will present you with the next error: `Both, the "header", and the "payload" query string parameters are missing`.

## Further Information

[Read more about how to build up a connection on aws.amazon.com](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html).

### Open websocket with header and payload

```
const api_header = {
  host: 'XXXX.appsync-api.YYYY.amazonaws.com',
  'x-api-key': '<YOUR APPSYNC API KEY>',
};

// payload should be an empty JSON object
const payload = {};

const base64_api_header = btoa(JSON.stringify(api_header));
const base64_payload = btoa(JSON.stringify(payload));

const appsync_url = url + '?header=' + base64_api_header + '&payload=' + base64_payload;

ws = new WebSocket(appsync_url, ['graphql-ws']);
```

Note that the *host* is `appsync-api` and **not** `appsync-realtime-api`

With this, you should see a 'ka' message and can go forward with the handshake (see next section).

### How to do the handshake

[See this document on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html)
[image]

## References

- [WebSocket API referene (mentioning of second parameter)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/WebSocket)
- [PHP implementation for WebSocket to AppSync](https://github.com/roshanlabh/php-appsync-consumer-example/blob/master/appsync-subscription.php)
- [Amazon's doc on how to connect to AppSync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-websocket-client.html)